# Generate two different index files for RTL and LTR support using Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, html-webpack-plugin, rtlcss

I am trying to have two different style files in my react application to support both RTL and LTR directions. Therefore, I am using RTLCSS and its Webpack plugin to generate two different files: (myfile.chunk.css and myfile.chunk.rtl.css).

However, in the index.html file generated by HtmlWebpackPlugin, one of them is injected. How can I have two index files like index.html and index.rtl.html?
The second file should contain RTL style files including RTL chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish what you are looking for, First read the plugin documentation for:

1. [Generating Multiple HTML Files](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#generating-multiple-html-files).
2. [Writing Your Own Templates](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates).

Now, to have control over your generated HTML you need to be aware that any additional key you add to the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` config will be accessible through `htmlWebpackPlugin.options`.

For example, adding `dir` key to the config:

**webpack.config.js**

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: 'Custom template',
    // Load a custom template (lodash by default)
    template: 'index.template.html',
    // Extra Key
    dir:'rtl'
  })
]
```

will be accessible in our template via `htmlWebpackPlugin.options.dir`:

**index.template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="<%=htmlWebpackPlugin.options.dir%>">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- print a list of all available keys -->
    <pre>
      <%=JSON.stringify(htmlWebpackPlugin)%>
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

That being said, we can switch to manual assets injection to have more control over which CSS files to include in the page, for instance `myproject.rtl.css` instead of `myproject.css`

**webpack.config.js**

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    .
    .
    .
    // disable automatic injection of assets
    inject: false,
  })
]
```

**index.template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="<%=htmlWebpackPlugin.options.dir%>">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <!-- manually inject css -->
    <%=
       Object.keys(htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks).map(
         key => htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[key].css.map(
           css=>`<link href="${htmlWebpackPlugin.options.dir == 'rtl' ?css.replace('.css','.rtl.css'):css}" rel="stylesheet">`)
           .join(''))
         .join('')
    %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- print a list of all available keys -->
    <pre>
      <%=JSON.stringify(htmlWebpackPlugin)%>
    </pre>
    <!-- manually inject js -->
    <%=
      Object.keys(htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks).map(
        key=>`<script type="text/javascript" src="${htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[key].entry}" defer></script>`)
        .join('')
    %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Applying the above will make it possible for you to generate `index.ltr.html` and `index.rtl.html` without hard coding bundle references.